# How to use select * when use join multiple table?

Tags: php, mysql

How to use `select *` when use join multiple table ?

Can i use `SELECT * , max(i_test.num)` for select all column in table `h_test` , `i_test` and `max(i_test.num)`

Like this code

```
$SQL = "SELECT * , max(i_test.num) FROM h_test INNER JOIN i_test ON i_test.pro_id = h_test.pro_id
        WHERE h_test.pro_id != '0' AND i_test.num > '5' GROUP BY h_test.pro_id order by i_test.num desc ";
```

Comment: Except this `h_test.pro_id` you will have indeterminate results for rest of the columns

Comment: you should never use `select *`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `select h_test.*, i_test.*`

i.e. when using Join queries, you should use `select table_name.*`

Comment: and try to avoid select *. Better provide all column names you want for better coding.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions (MAX, SUM, COUNT, etc) require the 'group by' clause.
Furthermore, the 'group by' has to have all the fields listed that are listed in the select clause that are not in an aggregate function.
Example:

```
SELECT fld1, fld2, fld3, COUNT(fld4), SUM(fld5)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY fld1, fld2, fld3
```

I have seen the aggregate used without the group by clause but that is an oddity, not the SQL standard and I am not sure what was the intention.